# Regular expression not matching subwords in phrase

Tags: java, regex

My program displays the matching results, but I want to sort the results as best match, second best match ans so on.

My text file contains the following line:

> `red or yellow`
>   `red'`
>   yellow'

So If I search for: `red or yellow`: I get the following results 
`'red or yellow`
`red`
`yellow`.
So what I want to do is to sort the found results as follows:

1. "red and yellow" 100% match
2. "red"             40% match
3. "yellow"          40% match

Any help is appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  String strLine;
  try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter   
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\textfile.txt"");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    Scanner input  = new Scanner (System.in);         
    System.out.print("Enter Your Search:  ");   // String key="red or yellow";
    String key = input.nextLine();

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {     
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key); // regex pattern to search for
      Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);  // src of text to search
      boolean b = false;
      while(b = m.find()) {                       
        System.out.println( " " + m.group()); // returns index and match
        // Print the content on the console
      }
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();              
  }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: For future reference - describe your problem in the question title. Titles such as "I have a problem", or derivatives thereof, are not helpful to the passing reader!

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed pattern and search space. The line (`strLine`) is your search space and `key` is the pattern. Fix:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key);
Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
```

Comment: Thanks, that have sorted half of my problem.

Comment: I want to sort the found results as follows:
 1."red and yellow" 100% match
 2."red" 40% match
 3."yellow" 40% match
Any help, you have sorted half of my problem by pointing out my silly mistake. I thank you for that.

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.