# How do sort my pattern match results as complete match, half a match and so on

Tags: java, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression not matching subwords in phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272988/regular-expression-not-matching-subwords-in-phrase)

My program displays the matching results, but I want to sort the results as complete match (100%), half a match and so on.
My text file contains the following line:

1. Red car
2. Red
3. Car

So If I search for: “red car”.  I get the following  results

1. Red car
2. Red
3. Car

So what I want to do is to sort the found results as follows:

1. "red car" 100% match
2. "red"      40% match
3. "car"      40% match

Any help is appreciated.

Any help is appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  String strLine;
  try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter   
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\textfile.txt"");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    Scanner input  = new Scanner (System.in);         
    System.out.print("Enter Your Search:  ");   // String key="red or yellow";
    String key = input.nextLine();

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {     
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key); // regex pattern to search for
      Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);  // src of text to search
      boolean b = false;
      while(b = m.find()) {                       
        System.out.println( " " + m.group()); // returns index and match
        // Print the content on the console
      }
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();              
  }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/11228384/1225328](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11228384/1225328)

Comment: Can you explain the logic some more? If you have a line containing "Red or yellow Red Yellow" and you search for "Red or yellow" I would expect it to match once, at the beginning of the string. Or did you mean you are searching for "Red" or "Yellow", in which case I would expect it to match 4 times, twice for each colour - but that's still not 100% (the string " or " is not matched).

Comment: sorry the text file contains three lines. Line 1 is "Red or yellow" Line 2 is "Red" and Line three is "Yellow". the first line is 100% match, so I want to sort them

Comment: I'm confused is "or" a string to be matched, or is it a logical operator? If it's a string to be matched, your first line matches 100% but the other two lines do not match at all. If it's a logical operator, then I don't understand why the first line is 100%. Sorry if I'm missing the obvious

Comment: you are right, it is a logical. my exmaple is completly wrong that is what is caused the confusion. Here is the real problem. the text file contains: line 1 is: "red car". line 2 is:"red" line 3 is"car" so red car would be 100% match where as red and car are 40% match each. any help is appreciated

Comment: you are right, it is a logical. my exmaple is completly wrong that is what is caused the confusion. Here is the real problem. the text file contains: line 1 is: "red car". line 2 is:"red" line 3 is"car" so red car would be 100% match where as red and car are 40% match each. any help is appreciated

Comment: Why only 40% each, why not 50%?

Comment: I just want a way to assign them a score and sort them based on the scoreing

Comment: I would appreciate any help or even a direction where I can get any sort of information relating to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are searching for "Red" or "Yellow", and or is the only logical operator you need  (no 'and' or 'xor') and you don't want to use any wildcards or regular-expressions in what you search for, then I would simply loop through, trying to match each String in turn against the line. In pseudo-code, something like:

```
foreach (thisLine: allLinesInTheFile) {
    numOfCharsMatching = 0
    foreach (thisString: allSearchStrings) {
         if (thisLine.contains(thisString) {
               numOfCharsMatching = numOfCharsMatching + thisString.length
         }
    }
    score = ( numOfCharsMatching / thisLine.length ) * 100
}
```

If you don't want spaces to count in your score, then you'd need to remove them from the thisString.length (and not allow them in your search terms)

One other problem is the numOfCharsMatching will be incorrect if matches can overlap (i.e. if searching for 'row' or 'brown' in 'brown row' it will say that there are 11 characters matching, longer than the length of the string. You could use a BitSet to track which characters have been involved in a match, something like:

```
foreach (thisLine: allLinesInTheFile) {
    whichCharsMatch = new BitSet()
    foreach (thisString: allSearchStrings) {
         if (thisLine.contains(thisString) {
               whichCharsMatch.set(startPositionOfMatch, endPositionOfMatch, true)
         }
    }
    score = ( numOfCharsMatching / thisLine.length ) * 100
}
```

Have a look at the BitSet javadoc, particularly the set and cardinality methods

Comment: By pseduo-code I mean, I haven't checked any method names and foreach comes from a completely different language!